# Dictionary<,> Binding to a Controller in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, reflection

I have a class like as below.

```
   public class ProductViewGridModel
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string PackageCode { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        public string ProductCategory { get; set; }
        public IDictionary<string, string> Localizations { get; set; }

    }
```

I rendered the model in to view like this.(foreach statement running into table, I'm not showing its here.)

```
 @foreach (var localization in Model.Localizations)
                {
                    var p = localization.Value;
                    <tr>
                        <td class="adminData">
                            <input class="k-textbox" type="text" value="@p" name="productView.Localizations[@localization.Key]" />
                            <input type="hidden" value="@p" name="productView.Localizations[@localization.Key]" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
```

And I have a button, the button sending form values to controller with ajax call.

Other model bindings are okay, but I want to bind all localization inputs to localizations model.
But localizations always null. How can I bind this ?.

Comment: The name is wrong, must be only Localizations[@localization.Key]

Comment: You are awesome man :) I almost write Defaultvaluebinder, you saved me :)

Comment: You can simplify all this to `foreach (var key in Model.Localizations.Keys) { @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Localizations[key]) }` (and no point adding the hidden input - its just creating invalid html and the model binder ignors it anyway)

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes, your solution is correct, thanks for advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input name is wrong. The default `modelbinder` will look for the property `Localizations`:

```
@foreach (var localization in Model.Localizations)
{
    var p = localization.Value;
    <tr>
        <td class="adminData">
            <input class="k-textbox" type="text" value="@p" name="Localizations[@localization.Key]" />
            <input type="hidden" value="@p" name="Localizations[@localization.Key]" />
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```